# Text (URL) converted to wrong Encoding

Tags: java, ios, url, text, encoding

this is a URL which I have in a text file. When my application reads the file in and converts it to a string it ends up with strange characters being added.

Before:

```
<p><a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="iframe_a">W3Schools.com</a></p>
```

After:

```
"%3Cp%3E%3Ca%20href%3D%22http%3A//www.w3schools.com%22%20target%3D%22iframe_a%22%3EW3Schools.com%3C/a%3E%3C/p%3E"
```

I'm aware that this is probably an encoding error, my question is why does it happen and only to URLS? How could I stop it from doing it in Java and iOS.

Comment: please show us the code snip for doing above job? [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The Content of the file you showed is no URL, it is a Piece of html. If you use it as an URL, all Special characters, not allowed in an URL will be encoded (e.g. a blank is %20). Probably you Need to parse the file and extract "http://www.w3schools.com" and use this part of the file as URL.

Answer (score 0):

The string you posted is not a URL, it's HTML that contains a URL.

You can't treat HTML as if it is a valid URL because it's not.

Answer (score 0):

As @Duncan_C said: there's HTML code around your url. You can use the [Jsoup library](https://jsoup.org/) to get rid of that. Once you've done that it will encode properly.

Here's how to do that:

```
String html = "<p><a href=\"http://www.w3schools.com\" target=\"iframe_a\">W3Schools.com</a></p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element link = doc.select("a").first();
String url = link.attr("href");
System.out.println(url);
```